Dynamically populate categories based on selected product type
Unable to access productTypeId inside foreach loop. In if (productType.Id == productTypeId)
 <select name="productType" id="productType" class="form-select">
     <option value="" selected>Choose Product Type...</option>
     @foreach (var productType in Model.ProductTypes)
     {
         <option value="@productType.Id">@productType.Name</option>
     }
 </select>

 <select name="category" id="category" class="form-select">
     <option value="" selected>Choose Category...</option>
 </select>

 <script>
     
     function populateCategories(productTypeId) {
         var categories = document.getElementById("category");
         categories.innerHTML = ""; 

         var defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
         defaultOption.text = "Choose Category...";
         defaultOption.value = "";
         categories.appendChild(defaultOption);
         
         var productTypeId;
         document.getElementById("productType").addEventListener("change", function () {
             var productTypeId = this.value;
             populateCategories(productTypeId); 
         });
     @foreach (var productType in Model.ProductTypes)
     {
         if (productType.Id == productTypeId)
         {
             @foreach (var category in productType.Categories)
             {
                 <text>
                                     var option = document.createElement("option");
                     option.text = "@category.Name";
                     option.value = "@category.Id";
                     categories.appendChild(option);
                 </text>
             }
         }
     }
         }

    
 </script>

I want to Access productTypeId inside foreach loop.OR is there Any other way of Dynamically populate categories.
